# Continuous async pinger class: InvalidOperation on Progress (List modified during enumeration)

Tags: c#, async-await, task, ping

I'm trying to write a class that continuosly ping "in background" a list of one or more devices, and report the results to a Progress object in the GUI main class. Im very new with async/await and Tasks, but my code seems to work fine on my pc, even if i know its not so good designed. But when i start the application in a different computer it throws an InvalidOperationException from the Progress object because the Dictionary in  is changed. I think it happens when i assign a new PingService to the same variable.
The PingService class starts pinging (SendPingAsync) a list of IP's on a function with a inf. loop that updates the PingServiceReply object for each iteration of the list and then "reporting" it to the Progress object.

What is the way for get it done, and what im doing wrong?

Here's the code.

PingSeviceReply class

```
public class PingServiceReply
{
    private Dictionary<string, bool> ipDictionary;

    internal PingServiceReply()
    {
        ipDictionary = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    }

    public void SetIpStatus(string ip, bool status)
    {
        if (ipDictionary.ContainsKey(ip))
        {
            ipDictionary[ip] = status;
        }
        else
        {
            ipDictionary.Add(ip, status);

        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, bool> GetStatusDictionary()
    {
        return ipDictionary;
    }

    public bool AreAllOnline()
    {
        foreach (bool value in ipDictionary.Values)
        {
            if (!value)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }

}
```

PingService class

```
    public class PingService
{
    private string name;
    private List<string> ipList;
    private IProgress<PingServiceReply> progress;
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;
    private int timeout;
    private Task tsk;

    public PingService(string name, List<string> ipList, int timeoutInMillliseconds, IProgress<PingServiceReply> progress)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.ipList = ipList;
        this.progress = progress;
        this.timeout = timeoutInMillliseconds;
    }

    public PingService(string name, string ip, int timeoutInMillliseconds, IProgress<PingServiceReply> progress)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.ipList = new List<string>();
        ipList.Add(ip);
        this.progress = progress;
        this.timeout = timeoutInMillliseconds;
    }

    public PingService()
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    private async Task ContinuousPingAsync()
    {
        var ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
        PingReply singleResponse;
        PingServiceReply ruleResponse = new PingServiceReply();


        while (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {

            foreach (string ip in ipList)
            {
                singleResponse = await ping.SendPingAsync(ip, timeout).ConfigureAwait(false);
                ruleResponse.SetIpStatus(ip, singleResponse.Status == IPStatus.Success);
            }
            progress.Report(ruleResponse);


        }

    }

    public void StartService()
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        tsk = ContinuousPingAsync();
    }

    public void StopService()
    {
        cts.Cancel();
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }

}
```

The progress object

```
IProgress<PingServiceReply> pingProgress = new Progress<PingServiceReply>(HandleSinglePing);
    private void HandleSinglePing(PingServiceReply report)
    {
        if (report.AreAllOnline())
        {
            //online
        }
        else
        {
            //offline
        }

    }
```

How i use all in the gui class, on the combobox selectedItemChanged event

```
    comboService.StopService();
    comboService = new PingService("Combo", (string) comboBox.SelectedItem, 1000, pingProgress);
    comboService.StartService();
```

Comment: What is the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: you to make the access to dictionary thread safe. Either use ConcurentDictionary or use locks in all public methods of PingService

Comment: The class `PingServiceReply` is not thread-safe, because is uses internally the also non-thread-safe class `Dictionary`. There is no apparent multithreading usage of this class in the code you have posted, but I assume that there is more code in your application that touches this class, and specifically its `GetStatusDictionary` method, resulting to multithreaded usage. In that case you should either synchronize all access to this class externally, or change its implementation to become thread-safe internally.

Comment: @PauloMorgado System.InvalidOperationException: La raccolta è stata modificata. L'operazione di enumerazione potrebbe non essere eseguita.
   in System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   in System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.ValueCollection.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   in AsyncPing.PingServiceReply.AreAllOnline()
   in GUI.Form1.HandleSinglePing(PingServiceReply report)
   in System.Progress`1.InvokeHandlers(Object state)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Understood, thank you for your reply. There isn't any other code related to these classes, and `GetStatusDictionary` is never used (i will delete it). Using `ConcurrentDictionary` in `PingServiceReply` apparently solved the problem. Is there a better way to implement the pinging funcionality? For example, if i dont call `StopService` on the `PingService` object before overriding it, the Task keeps pinging, so i think this isnt a good implementation